# linq to sql ordering issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, compiler-construction, sql-order-by

I have currently an IQueryable that consists of multiple concats of linq queries, lets call it baseQuery.  I want to call skip and take on this baseQuery object, but I have been informed by the compiler that I have to call OrderBy first.  Basically the order is already correct inside of my baseQuery object, the order I want everything in is in the order I already called concat.  So how do I tell the compiler that its already in the order I want?

Comment: 'I have been informed by the compiler that I have to call OrderBy first' Can you expand on what that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the order you want using ORDER BY, you cannot guarantee  that LINQ will return it in some order. It is subject to things like the data access methods and join-types the DBMS chooses. The order might be what you want in some cases, but without specifying it explicitly with ORDER BY, you cannot be assured that this will always be returned in the right order.